# How to escape double quotes for Primefaces SelectOneMenu in Application level?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using PrimeFaces, when the content of `itemLabel` of a `p:selectOneMenu` has the char double quote ("), the `selectOneMenu` stop working (can't select the item).
For example, in the code below is not possible to select: Item "2"

Is there a way to escape or replace the double quotes in every `selectOneMenu` from the entire application?

Maybe using a tag decorator or a tag handler?

```java
@Named(value = "bb")
@ViewScoped
@Getter @Setter
public class BB implements Serializable {

    List<String> items;
    String selectedItem;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Item 1");
        items.add("Item \"2\""); // <= note the double quotes here.
        items.add("Item 3");
    }

    public void logSelected() {
        System.out.println(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

```
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bb.selectedItem}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bb.items}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:commandButton action="#{bb.logSelected}"
                         process="@form"
                         update="@form"
                         value="GO"/>
    </h:form>
```

When I try to select 'Item "2"', the following error is shown on console log:

```html
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-label="Item "2""]
    at Function.ga.error (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at ga.tokenize (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at ga.compile (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at ga.select (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at ga (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at Function.ga.matches (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at Function.r.filter (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at E (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at r.fn.init.filter (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:2)
    at c.setLabel (eNptjUsOgzAMRE9E2XMbEwwkcmxjJ6qQenh-i6qF1UhvnmbUYsYRAnqXloq2tle8kn_02wUxvKGswsjF_4qfnUapTpFPp1KJGRqCVWrpkrcMLB5MiNAeBX9HPX9n8HmAAgecSHqgnW7lbUr_.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1558274343370:38)
```

Comment: You don't mention what version of PrimeFaces you are using?  I just tested with PrimeFaces 7.0 and your scenario works fine.

Comment: Good point @Melloware. I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2.5. Good to know that this issue is fixed in version 7.0. But, If we can't upgrade right now, do you know any way to fix this in all `selectOneMenu` at once (without patching Primefaces sources)?

Comment: Nope I think it has to be fixed in the source code.  Maybe try upgrading to 6.2.20 Elite to see if its fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verified as fixed in PrimeFaces 7.0.

However, it may also be fixed in 6.2.X depending on which fix was applied.

6.2.9: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3982

7.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3466

It appears this isse was reintroduced in PrimeFaces 10.0.0 and fixed in version 10.0.9:

10.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7878

Comment: This bug reappeared in PrimeFaces 10.0.0 and was fixed for v10.0.9